# Shell script: parse blank spaces correctly

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

In the code below I was expecting an output like this:

```
Transmission_Downloads/The.Last.Man.On.Earth.S02E04.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]/Torrent-Downloaded-from-ExtraTorrent.cc.txt
Transmission_Downloads/Fargo.S02E01.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]/Torrent-Downloaded-from-ExtraTorrent.cc.txt
Transmission_Downloads/Nightwish - Showtime Storytime (2013) 1080p 5.1/SEMEAR.txt
```

But what I do got was this

```
Transmission_Downloads/The.Last.Man.On.Earth.S02E04.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]/Torrent-Downloaded-from-ExtraTorrent.cc.txt
Transmission_Downloads/Fargo.S02E01.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]/Torrent-Downloaded-from-ExtraTorrent.cc.txt
Transmission_Downloads/Nightwish
-
Showtime
Storytime
(2013)
1080p
5.1/SEMEAR.txt
```

What should I do for my shell script parse blank spaces on file and folder names correctly? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

#opcao -s nao mostra o texto na tela
echo "Digite sua senha"
read -s answer

root_folder="/home/pi/"
user="pi"
server="*****"
local_folder="/home/dellcloud2"

#Colocar aqui os paths dos arquivos que deseja puxar
array=(
    "Transmission_Downloads/The.Last.Man.On.Earth.S02E04.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]/Torrent-Downloaded-from-ExtraTorrent.cc.txt"
    "Transmission_Downloads/Fargo.S02E01.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]/Torrent-Downloaded-from-ExtraTorrent.cc.txt"
    "Transmission_Downloads/Nightwish - Showtime Storytime (2013) 1080p 5.1/SEMEAR.txt"
)
for i in ${array[@]}; do
    #sshpass -p $answer rsync -aP $user@$server:$root_folder$i $local_folder
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Escape variables when you use them. All the time. `"${array[@]}"`, `"$i"`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `"${array[@]}"` to preserve white space. The quotes around the array plus the wildcard `@` together enable this.

This also works with positional parameters, i.e. `"$@"` gives you an array of the command line arguments, properly quoted as they were given.